# CSS Positioning Fixed in Parent Container

Tags: css

How can I have an element to be fixed positioned while its width is always 100% of its parent element?

The parent element is as follows:

```
div.panel-left
{
    width: 35%;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    display: table;
    text-align: right;
}
```

Thanking you

Note: other similar questions I saw on stackoverflow do not solve the width issue stated above.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

Css

```
div.inner {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   ...
}
```

Html

```
<div class="panel-left">
   <div class="inner">something</div>
</div>
```

Comment: yes that solves the width issue but not the 'fixed' issue. The inner div should be fixed also.

Comment: Ok, can you explain more about the 'fixed'-issue in your question? Is it fixed positioned on the page or some other element? A wider example would be nice.

Comment: fixed on page, but its width should not grow more than the parent div it should be within

Comment: @Imran Omar Bukhsh Fixed elements are relative to the window of your browser and not relative to a container, you can't specify a % width and expect it to adapt to a parent, since the parent is your window.

Comment: @Andres Ilich : ok, yeah i could not solve it that way, so I set its width dynamically using jquery to be equal to its container